# Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 installation on AMD based machine not making use of Nvidia drivers

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-geforce, amd-ryzen

I recently purchased a Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6 laptop with Windows 10 home edition installed. It's CPU is AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with integrated Radeon Graphics and system memory of 16 GB and GPU is Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 (video memory: 4 GB, GDDR6). In the BIOS menu, I had disabled the secure boot option with the Graphic Device set to default option of 'Dynamic graphics' (Other available option is 'Discrete Graphics'). I dual boot installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the system using the 'Safe Graphics' option provided in the GNU GRUB menu. I successfully managed to install Ubuntu, but it is not making use of the Nvidia Graphics card and is instead using the integrated Radeon graphics. I tried looking for the solution to my problem online, but could not find concrete answers. I am a bit confused as to how to proceed to rectify this issue and would like to receive some help regarding the same. Here are some of the commands I tried based on info available online:

```
    $ dkms status
    $
```

No output observed from the command above.

```
    $ nvidia-smi
    
    NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make 
    sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

```
    $ nvidia-settings; lspi -V | grep VGA

    
    ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


    ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


    (nvidia-settings:16830): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:19:56.983: g_object_unref: 
    assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
    ** Message: 14:19:56.988: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
    ** Message: 14:19:56.988: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

The above command also opens a blank dialogue box named 'NVIDIA X server settings'

```
    $ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
    
    ii  libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library              
    ii  libnvidia-common-470                        470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries             
    ii  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package             
    ii  libnvidia-compute-470:i386                  470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  i386         NVIDIA libcompute package             
    ii  libnvidia-decode-470:amd64                  470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries            
    ii  libnvidia-decode-470:i386                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries              
    ii  libnvidia-encode-470:amd64                  470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library            
    ii  libnvidia-encode-470:i386                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
    ii  libnvidia-extra-470:amd64                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
    ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
    ii  libnvidia-gl-470:amd64                      470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
    ii  libnvidia-gl-470:i386                       470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
    ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
    ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic  5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1     amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-27
    ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04  5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1     amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-470 for the generic-hwe-20.04 flavour
    ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic  5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1     amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-27 (objects)
    rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-37-generic  5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2     amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-37 (objects)
    ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-38-generic  5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1     amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-38 (objects)
    ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic  5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2+1   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-40 (objects)
    ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-27-generic   5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1     amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-27-generic
    ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-38-generic   5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1     amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-38-generic
    ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-40-generic   5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2+1   amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-40-generic
    ii  nvidia-compute-utils-470                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
    ii  nvidia-kernel-common-470                    470.57.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64       Shared files used with the kernel module
    ii  nvidia-kernel-source-470                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
    ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.16~0.20.04.1         all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
    ii  nvidia-settings                             470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
    ii  nvidia-utils-470                            470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
    ii  screen-resolution-extra                     0.18build1               all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470               470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

```
$ uname -r

5.11.0-41-generic
```

```
$ apt list --installed | grep 'linux-headers'


WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2 amd64 [installed]
linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0.41.45~20.04.19 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

```
$ apt list --installed | grep 'linux-image'


WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.11.0.41.45~20.04.19 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

```
$ grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/*

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist nvidiafb
```

```
$ grep nvidia /lib/modprobe.d/*
$
```

The above command provides no output.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25e2 (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1638 (rev c5)
```

When I go to **Software and Updates** -> **Additional Drivers**, the option of **X.org X server--Nouveau** is selected.

Comment: Try selecting the recommended Nvidia driver then apply and reboot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thak you. It worked